# flask NoAppException but flask run works

Tags: flask

I have the following structure:

```
app_dir/
|     myapi/
|          __init__.py
|     myapi_app.py
```

where `myapi_app.py` is

```
from myapi import create_app, db

app = create_app()
```

and `myapi/__init__.py` is

```
import logging
import os

from logging.handlers import RotatingFileHandler
from flask import Flask, request, current_app
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
from myapi.config import Config

db = SQLAlchemy()

def create_app(config_class=Config):
    app = Flask(__name__)
    app.config.from_object(config_class)

    db.init_app(app)

    ...

    return app
```

When I set `FLASK_APP=myapi_app.py` and run `flask run` from the `app_dir` directory, the flask service starts. However, when I make a request, I get the following error: `flask.cli.NoAppException: Could not import "myapi_app".` Where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that you are setting $FLASK_APP to the file in which the app variable is stored, you should instead set it to the python object path, e.g.

```
FLASK_APP=myapi_app:app
```

However, this is not necessary, as you could also just do:

```
FLASK_APP=myapi
```

as Flask will look for a `create_app` function in the package on its own.